# Developing against a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

My superior once told me that a bad way of calling a web service or a wcf service is treating it like its a referenced assembly i.e. instantiate a class and call the methods.

I don't see any other way of doing it though.  Are there some best practices that I should be following when I interact with external web services / services or is this fine:

```
public class ServiceProxyManager : IServiceProxyManager
{
    private Service1Soap _externalService;

    public ServiceProxyManager()
    {
        _externalService = new Service1SoapClient();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's cleaner if you inject the web service into the code that uses it. That way you can write tests by mocking out the interface. I've had a lot of success with that approach in the past.

Of course *something* will have to create an interface of the service, but that doesn't have to be the code that calls into it...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by injecting the web service into the code that uses it.

Comment: Instead of creating it in the constructor to `ServiceProxyManager`, accept it as a parameter. Wrap it in an interface so you can use anything which "looks like" the service, including mocks.

Comment: Oh ok yeah I have done so.  But otherwise do you think calling it like a class is fine?

Comment: What do you mean by "calling it like a class"? How else would you call it?

Comment: I guess my superior was trying to say he doesn't like using the proxy classes that visual studio generates.  But I don't see what the problem with them is.

Comment: Try to find out how he'd do it instead.